# Python : How to set environment variables on VM windows

Tags: python, windows, path, environment-variables, virtual

I want to write a python script that adds env variables to PATH. This script will be executed from ssh to windows virtual machine. I tried 2 methods and no one works.

Method  1 :

```
os.system("setx /M PATH "'"%PATH%;path1;path2"'"")
```

Method 2 :

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(["path1"])
```

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the behaviour when you run the two methods?

Comment: my application is not running , however when I set env variables from GUI it works

Comment: I have a strange problem : when I run the application from the VM it works correctly and I see the env vars in the path , however when I run it from ssh to virtual machine with a python script it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need an administrative command prompt.

Try:
setx EC2_HOME "" /M

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this as a variation to your second method

```
os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join([os.environ["PATH"], "path1"])
```

Also check out some of the documentation here related to running python on Windows machines https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html

Specifically it is mentioned that you can set environment variables outside of your python environment by using the following syntax

```
 set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

Finally, I found the problem, I was setting this env variables with running a subprocess that execute another script, when I set this env vars from the script without a subprocess, it works and the two methods works :)